# One Time Loop in java?

Tags: java, loops, time

I have tried making a loop in java that only runs once,

```
package com.notelek.programs.flat;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import com.notelek.programs.flat.input.Controller;

public class Game {
    public static int time;
    public Controller controls;

    public Game(){
        controls = new Controller();
    }

    public void tick(Boolean[] key){
        time++;
        Boolean forward = key[KeyEvent.VK_W];
        Boolean back = key[KeyEvent.VK_S];
        Boolean left = key[KeyEvent.VK_A];
        Boolean right = key[KeyEvent.VK_D];
        Boolean turnLeft = key[KeyEvent.VK_LEFT];
        Boolean turnRight = key[KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT];
        for(Boolean i = true; i == true; i = false){
            forward = true;
            back = true;
            left = true;
            right = true;
            turnLeft = true;
            turnRight = true;
        }
        controls.tick(forward,back,left,right,turnLeft,turnRight);
    }    
}
```

That is my code, I need to set the forward backward left right turnleft turnright variables all to true, and then back to false quickly (within a second) Does anyone know a simple way of doing this?

Comment: Do you need the loop if it runs only once?

Comment: Why do you need a loop? Also why are you changing the values soon after initialization? If you need the values as mentioned inside the loop, why not initialize them with the same values e.g. `Boolean forward = true;`?

Answer (score 3):

How quickly are we talking, here?  If you want to switch it within a second (much, much faster than a second), just do:

```
forward = true;
back = true;
left = true;
right = true;
turnLeft = true;
turnRight = true;
forward = false;
back = false;
left = false;
right = false;
turnLeft = false;
turnRight = false;
```

If you're looking for a toggle that you can manipulate, I would make your own method:

```
public void toggle() {
    forward = !forward;
    back = !back;
    // and so on
}
```

... then invoke it after a certain amount of milliseconds have passed.

In the spirit of answering the question asked, though, if you really, really, *really* want to use a loop that only runs once, for some reason... here's the syntax for it:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: No, I want to switch them, BUT I only want to switch them once when they are in a method.

Comment: Then put them in their own method, like `toggle()` above, and invoke that whenever you want.  It will switch them back and forth.

Comment: :)  Happens to the best of us.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want a loop, use this:

```
do {
    your code here
} while (false);
```

IMO, this is a bit silly...

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use a loop? If all you want to do is make something wait a second, why not use a wait command:

[Thread.sleep(int milliseconds)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)

You can just execute the block of code you want, wait a prescribed number of milliseconds and then execute another block of code:

```
int milliseconds = 1000;

forward = true;
back = true;
left = true;
right = true;
turnLeft = true;
turnRight = true;
Thread.sleep(milliseconds)
forward = false;
back = false;
left = false;
right = false;
turnLeft = false;
turnRight = false;
```

Comment: Again, I just want it to be set and then unset quickly inside a method, and only once per program run

Comment: Well, you could set `int milliseconds = 1;` or you could just remove the timer entirely and it would be nearly instantaneous.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly try something like this:

> ```
> for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
> {
>      Boolean state = (i == 0);
>      forwards = state;
>      back = state;
>      left = state;
>      right = state;
>      turnLeft = state;
>      turnRight = state;
>
>      // Optional sleep
>      int milliseconds = 100;
>      Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
> }
> ```

The loop will go round once, set all to `true` (i == 0) then on the next repetion will set all to `fasle`, then quit.

The `Thread.sleep()` is optional depending if you need the values to stay what they are for a short period.